# Why is line number 22 necessay?

Tags: c

I am trying to generate all the Armstrong number from 0 to 999. I can't understand why my code doesn't work if I remove the `sum=0;` statement at the bottom of the program (line 22).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, n=999, rem, num, sum=0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        num=i;
        while(num != 0)
        {
            rem = num%10;
            num = num/10;
            sum = sum+(rem*rem*rem);

        }
        if (sum == i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
        sum=0;
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It'd be easier to understand if you put it at the beginning of the loop, for the same outcome.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the `sum`?

Comment: On every iteration of the outer loop sum gets set to 0. Is this not the functionality you were looking for?

Comment: All numbers <100, with one or two digits, are not calculated the right way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just resetting the sum so that each iteration of the `for` loop has a fresh, zeroed `sum`.

If you don't do this, each iteration of the loop will keep `sum` as whatever value it was from the prior iteration, thus compounding the summation and giving incorrect values!

As mentioned in the comments, it's traditionally easier to understand if this is done at the beginning of the loop, and in conjunction with that, it's better still to keep variable scopes as narrow as possible, *e.g.*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int num = i;

        while(num != 0)
        {
            int rem = num % 10;

            num = num / 10;
            sum = sum + (rem * rem * rem);
        }

        if (sum == i)
        {
            printf("%d\n", sum);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even better than just moving the assignment to `sum` to the top of the loop would be moving its declaration into the loop.  Also that of `num`.  And `rem` could be pushed all the way into the `while` loop.  Keeping variable scope as narrow as possible serves multiple good purposes.  Among them, in this case, is that it would be clearer that the value of `sum` is specific to one iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: That's very true! Feel free to push an edit and I'll update it! :D

Comment: You can narrow the scope of `i` further too using `for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )`.  Or even `for( int i = 0, n = 999; i < n; i++ )`, though `n` could be eliminated altogether.  conio.h is also unused here.

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop, the first usage of sum is `sum = sum + (rem*rem*rem);`, so if you do not want to use the value of the sum from the previous iteration, you have to reset its value to zero at the beginning of each iteration of the for loop. In your code, you reset its value to zero just before the for loop, and at the end of each iteration (line 22), which does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

An Armstrong number N is where the sum of the individual digits (say, A, B, C), raised to the power of the number of digits, equals the number itself.

```
N = A^3 + B^3 + C^3
```

So to calculate this for 0-999, you need a loop. In each iteration of the loop you need to start the summation over again from 0. Take `i=10` and `i=11` from your loop as an example. Neither is an Armstrong number, but they should be:

```
i=10: 1^2 + 0^2 = 1
i=11: 1^2 + 1^2 = 2
```

Without resetting `sum`, you're using the results of the previous numbers calculation:

```
i=10: 1^2 + 0^2 + 9^1 (+ 8^1 + 7^1 + ...) ≠ 1
i=11: 1^2 + 1^2 + (1^2 + 0^2 + 9^1) + ... ≠ 2
```

Comment: I'm not a matematician but on Wikipedia the definition of Amstrong numbers is different.

Comment: Yeah I never heard of it before, the search result I used skimped on the 'raised to the power of the number of digits" part. Either way, the point remains. Will edit.